# Bash script: parse subdirectory and not current directories

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to parse subdirectory names, but the output breaks the names up into individual words.

Eg. If the subdirectory name is "Hello World", the output will be:

```
.  
Hello  
World
```

The following code works, but the output includes the current directory, which I don't want:

```
find "$my_dir" -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 |
    while IFS= read -rd '' dir;
        do 
            echo "$dir"; 
        done
```

I'm trying to include an if statement that eliminates the current directory from the output, but it seems the code still sees individual words for each subdirectory name:

```
find "$my_dir" -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 |  
    while IFS= read -rd '' dir;
        do 
            if ["$dir" != "."]; then
                echo "$dir"
            fi
        done
```

Comment: Title should read "subdirectories and not current directory."

Comment: You can [edit] your question to fix that. Also, what do you intend to with the directory names after this? For example, `shopt -s dotglob; dirs=( */ )` will give you an array with all subdirectory names, so depending on what you want to do, that's an option.

Answer (score 0):

The breaking on spaces occurs in your `read` command, but you don't need this anyway. Also, your `if` logic is flawed. It would work only if `my_dir` equals to `.`, otherwise `find` would not generate a `.` in its output. Finally, you state in your example, that you want only the names of the directories, not the whole path, but in the way you wrote it, `find` would pass the path to stdout.

Here is an easier solution:

```
find "$my_dir" -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \;|tail -n +2
```

The trick here is the `tail` command. You want to exclude the starting directory (`$my_dir`) from the output. `find` always outputs this directory first (unless you explicitly require depth-first traversal), so you simply have to drop the first line from the resulting output.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it, use the `-mindepth` option, which can be used here to exclude the topmost directory in your tree

```
find "$my_dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0
```

However, since you also have `-maxdepth` limiting the depth, why not just use a `for` loop

```
for dir in "$my_dir"/*
do
    [[ -d "$dir" ]] || continue    # only directories
    echo "${dir/*\/}"              # just basename
done
```